# How can I access session vars of a website from a C# app?

Tags: c#, web-applications, session-variables, xamarin

I am developing an app with Xamarin.iOS and I need to log into my website. For now I managed to send a hardcoded cookie to the login page of the website and it logs me in. This is my first problem: how can I log in, without sending a hardcoded cookie?

And second: In the login function from the website, there are set some session vars and I need to access them in the app, but I have no idea how to do it.

Does anyone has some insight over this?

Comment: instead of setting them on `Session` you may use `Query String`.

Answer (score 0):

“This is my first problem: how can I log in, without sending a hardcoded cookie?” – you need to send a http request with appropriate post parameters and then application will send back the login cookie you can use for subsequent requests. Not sure how to do this in Xamarin.iOS though.

“And second: In the login function from the website, there are set some session vars and I need to access them in the app, but I have no idea how to do it.” – Short answer is you can’t. I’d suggest using query string as Rahul already suggested or creating a web service you can use instead.